# Docker container start up very slowly with 180G nfs volume

Tags: docker

We added a 180G nfs (aws efs) volume to my docker-compose recently, and it took about 7 minutes to start up, if we remove the nfs volume, it can start up in 1 minute, and we did some testing, the larger the nfs, the slower the startup.

Does anyone know why? Or is there some way to see what was the docker doing? I out put the docker logs, but only successful messages.

```
2022-04-13T06:28:46.662408516Z Hosting environment: Production
2022-04-13T06:28:46.662443259Z Content root path: /app
2022-04-13T06:28:46.662536439Z Now listening on: http://[::]:8002
2022-04-13T06:28:46.662550521Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

My docker version: 20.10.14.
My docker compose version: 1.29.2.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:      
    app:
        image: xxxx
        restart: always
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
        ports:
            - "8002:8002"
        volumes:
            - "./BinaryObjects/Static:/app/App_Data/BinaryObjects/Static"
            - "./BinaryObjects/Temp:/app/App_Data/BinaryObjects/Temp"
```

/BinaryObjects is the root path of nfs.

Comment: It's the container slow to start, or just your application running in the container? How long does it take to run a container that just launches /bin/sh? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @BMitch, sorry for the delay, there is an asp.net core 2.2 application running in the container, if only launch the /bin/sh, it is very quick. that's weird.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with your application. You should provide a [mcve] of an application that experiences this issue.

Comment: @BMitch I have submitted the issue to the dotnet-docker github, there are details in the issue https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3714, thank you anyway.

Comment: Update: it is not related to the docker, it is related to my dotnet application, if I move the NFS folder out of my application folder, the docker container can start up normally.